# set year range in single daterangepicker jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, date-range, daterangepicker

i have used single date range picker from [here](https://www.daterangepicker.com/)

```
<input type="text" name="birthday" value="{{old(birthday)}}" />

<script>
$(function() {
  $('input[name="birthday"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minYear: 1901,
    maxYear: parseInt(moment().format('YYYY'),10)
  }
});
</script>
```

Above code gives me month and year dropdown. I want to specify year range so i tried below:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
 var year = (new Date()).getFullYear();
   var startYear = year-18;
    var endYear = year-110;

      $('input[name="birthday"]').daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker: true,
        showDropdowns: true,
        minYear: startYear ,
        maxYear: endYear 
      }
    });
    </script>
```

But thats not working. Also I want to set starting date based on min/max year Or input will be blank at start.

How can i set that year range and default null/date based on min/max year?

Please help and guide. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The end Date Should greater than the start date and your javascript code has error;
Try this

```
<script>
  $(function() {
   var year = (new Date()).getFullYear();
   var startYear = year-110;
   var endYear = year-18;
  $('input[name="birthday"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minYear: startYear ,
    maxYear: endYear 
  
      });
   });
 </script>
```